# Ads on low content but high engagement (ish?) site?

Tags: google-ads, web-applications, online

I've been running an online game for a few years now, where you guess the results of football matches in major tournaments. It started with a small group of friends, but has been slowly growing and I'm expecting a couple of hundred users for the next big tournament. This is just a hobby and I want to keep it that way, but I thought I could add some ads to the site to get back at least some of the server costs.

I went to Google as a first option, but they complain there is not enough content on my site for ads. Makes sense: it's really just a list of results and how much you scored, and most of that is hidden behind a log in screen. And it's only active for a couple of weeks a year during a tournament, then lays dormant.

Is there any feasible way of showing ads and getting some revenue on a site like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can only expect to make $5.00 RPM from ads on a website.  That is five dollars for every 1000 visitors.    You would only make a couple dollars from your next tournament at most.

Ad networks have minimum payment thresholds.  They won't send payment until you have accrued $100 in earnings.

The small amount of content on your site is only one of your problems.   You don't have enough traffic to actually get paid.

Comment: Thanks! I think that's 1000 impressions rather than visitors, and I easily get a couple of thousand per tournament... but reaching $100 would be a long shot. So it looks like if I could get ads on there I would cover my server costs and then some - which is what I was hoping for - but it would take years before I actually get them paid out.

Oh well.